# Grab multiple .attr values from multiple div elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab multiple data attribute values from multiple div elements with the same class, for example:

```
'<div class="col-2">Category: <span class="title-cat tempcat" data-category="' + catId + '">'+ categoryName +'</span></div>'
```

I'm trying to grab the `data-category` attribute however the issue here is that there are multiple instances of this row so I want to build a list of all the `data-categories` that I then pass with AJAX.

What I have so far builds a list and keeps inserting the first rows value in the list:

```
var tempcat = $.map($('.title-cat.tempcat'), function() {
  return $('.title-cat.tempcat').attr('data-category');
});
```

It's passing tempcat: `154, 154` when there are two rows where it should say `154, 174`

Comment: The `.attr()` method will retrieve the attribute of the first element in the jQuery object, therefore you need to use the method on each item in the collection. Here is a one liner that will create an array of the attributes: `$('.title-cat.tempcat').map((_, el) => $(el).attr('data-category')).get()` [(example)](https://jsfiddle.net/tfqzx9k2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the same item each time because `attr` grabs the first one. You'll need to select something different - the item in the array:

```
var tempcat = $.map($('.title-cat.tempcat'), function(el) {
    return $(el).attr('data-category');
});
```

Comment: THANKS! works great, ill have to wait 7 min to award the answer thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're selecting all `.title-cat.tempcat` elements in the `map()` handler and calling `attr()` on a collection of elements only looks at the first in the set.

To solve the problem use the `this` keyword to reference the current element:

```js
var tempcat = $('.title-cat.tempcat').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('category');
}).get();

console.log(tempcat);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2">Category: <span class="title-cat tempcat" data-category="154">#154</span></div>
<div class="col-2">Category: <span class="title-cat tempcat" data-category="157">#157</span></div>
```

Comment: This is returning `tempcat:[object Object]`

Comment: My bad - I forgot to add `.get()`. I updated the answer and added an example for you